# PHP: problems with upload files while refreshing page

Tags: php, file, upload

I'm Just working on a simple form in PHP but i have a problem, i have many fields in my form and one of these is a file input type, if there are no issues with the file uploaded but an error occurred on another field, How can I ( in the refreshed page) maintain the file previously uploaded?

Answer (score 2):

Edit: We understood what you want, but this is not possible, filling the file-input again automatically after validation. **The user has to select his files again, this is how browsers works, for security matters.**

Well, since you know what you're doing, you dont really need a script, you really need some help/ideas on how to approach what you want. What I would do is:

 

- Save the path of the uploaded file in session user data variable, like `$_SESSION['uploaded_file']`, and retrieve it after error.

- Use AJAX, different form, to upload the file before user hit submit.


Obs: If the user gives up on completing the form even though he uploaded a file, his files will be on your server, 'stealing' some useful space. So I don't know if this is a really good approach, but a good one, would be using different forms, disassembling the upload action from the form's informations.


**Real example**: If  user is filling out a form to be a member of your website/forum/whatever, just let him upload the profile picture **later, only when his account is really active**. You could be saving some trouble.

**Another one**: If the user just wants to change profile picture, also make the uploading action to have no influence (and vice-versa) with his profile informations and etc. This is a trouble-saver, and a better approaching solution.

But, if you're like uploading a photo to a gallery and setting description and etc for the picture, then you could be using of a more elaborated validation, using javascript/ajax to check if fields are being filled correctly before submiting data.

Comment: In addition to the first approach; I've used it multiple times like that, but at first I move the uploaded file to a - protected - temporary directory (not the server's tmp dir). Every night I'll let a cronjob cleanup that directory, by deleting all files that are older then 24 hours (after 24 hours they have either completed the form or have stopped their attempts)

Comment: it doesen't work:

example

<form>
<input type="text" ....>
<input type="text" ....>
    .
<input type="text" ....>
<input type="file"...> 
</form>
if i have an error in one "TEXT" field and NOT in File , when the refreshed page appear i would have to re-insert only the text one and i would have near the box named Choose a file "the file name" (previously uploaded).

Comment: We understood what you want, but this is not possible, filling the file-input again automatically after validation. The user has to select his files again, this is how browsers works, for security matters. Think about it: If the form could select your files automatically, the form could easily has a file-input hidden, searching your computer for some specific files, like passwords.txt. So, you have to do this 'workarounds' to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

On your upload code first save the values into SESSION like:

```
$_SESSION[name] = $_POST[name];
```

then print it into your INPUTS like:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?=$_SESSION[name]?>">
```

Don't forget to use session_start().

Or look for javascript alternatives

Comment: it doesen't work:

example

<form>
<input type="text" ....>
<input type="text" ....>
    .
<input type="text" ....>
<input type="file"...> 
</form>
if i have an error in one "TEXT" field and NOT in File , when the refreshed page appear i would have to re-insert only the text one and i would have near the box named Choose a file "the file name" (previously uploaded).